# Solving a puzzle in Prolog about time constraints

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle, program-slicing

Stuck on a Prolog problem. I know the answer (because I did it on paper first), but I cannot figure out how to get Prolog to come up with the answer.

Problem:

> Bill eats a snack every night, having a different fruit and different
>   nuts each night. From the statements below, identify what Bill had for
>   a snack for each weeknight last week.
>
> a) The apple was eaten later in the week than the mango.
>
> b) The banana was eaten later in the week than both the almonds and
>   peanuts, but earlier in the week than the pear.
>
> c) The cashews were eaten earlier in the week than both the banana and
>   the apricot, but later in the week than the peanuts.
>
> d) The pecans were not eaten the evening after the almonds.
>
> e) Bill ate walnuts one night.
>
> Note that the problem is about 5 weeknights (Monday through Friday),
>   and mentions 5 kinds of fruit and 5 kinds of nuts. Your program should
>   solve the problem and print out the solution, which will be a set of 5
>   triples like (Monday, apple, pecans), ... (Friday, mango, walnuts).
>
> Clearly, these are not the correct answers, but just values to show
>   you what the solution will look like.

Code so far:

```erlang
before_in_week(X, Y, Days) :-
    nth1(Xi, Days, X),
    nth1(Yi, Days, Y),
    Xi < Yi.

print_solve([Head|Tail]) :-
    write(Head),
    nl,
    print_solve(Tail).  

solve(A) :-
  % all triples
  A = [[day1, fruit1, nut1],
       [day2, fruit2, nut2],
       [day3, fruit3, nut3],
       [day4, fruit4, nut4],
       [day5, fruit5, nut5]],

  Days = [monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday],
  Days = [day1, day2, day3, day4, day5],

  Fruits = [apple,banana,pear,mango,apricot],
  permutation(Fruits, [fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, fruit4, fruit5]),

  Nuts = [almonds,pecans,cashews,peanuts,walnuts],
  permutation(Nuts, [nut1, nut2, nut3, nut4, nut5]),

  % clue 1 - mango before apple
  fruit5 \= mango,
  member([C1,mango,_], A),
  member([C2,apple,_], A), before_in_week(C1,C2,Days),
  % clue 2 - banana after almonds and peanuts, but before pear
  fruit5 \= banana,
  member([C1,banana,_], A),
  member([C2,pear,_], A), before_in_week(C1,C2,Days),
  member([C3,_,almonds], A), before_in_week(C3,C1,Days),
  member([C4,_,peanuts], A), before_in_week(C4,C1,Days),
  % clue 3 - cashews before banana and apricot, but after peanuts
  nut5 \= peanuts,
  member([C1,_,cashews], A),
  member([C2,_,peanuts], A), before_in_week(C1,C2,Days),
  member([C3,banana,_], A), before_in_week(C3,C1,Days),
  member([C4,apricot,_], A), before_in_week(C4,C1,Days),
  % clue 4 - pecans not night after almonds
  nut5 \= almonds,
  % clue 5 - ate walnuts one night


  print_solve(A).
```

Comment: I added a tag. peruse it to see if its answers help. also, what is the question? does the code work, as shown? what is the query you're trying?

Comment: @false (preemptively). before I added the highlighting, however deficient, I didn't even see the small cased logvars. YMWV.

Comment: `fruit5 \= mango` is always going to be true. both atoms are different. Prolog's variables must start with an Upper Case Letter, like `Fruit5`. for the *"ununifiable"* goal (`Fruit5 \= mango`) to succeed, the logvar (`Fruit5`) should be already instantiated by the time the goal is tried (appears in the overall predicate), otherwise that goal will fail because a free logvar is always unifiable with a given value by being instantiated with it.

Comment: Of interest: [Rosetta Code](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) - [Zebra Puzzle](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zebra_puzzle) - [Prolog versions](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zebra_puzzle#Prolog)

Comment: `I did it on paper first` You probably have no idea how much that puts you ahead as someone with an ability to problem solve.

Comment: @Will, the [original](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rj6doZ1bFo) color highlighting.

Comment: (I meant "non-unifiable" goal there)

Answer (score 2):

First, there is really no need to print anything manually. Prolog's top level does this for you, if you enter the query `solve(A).` yet,

second, there is no solution. That is really what you are interested in. There is a very simple and very general method to narrow down the source of failure. Simply generalize away all the goals, one after the other. I like to do this by adding a `*` in front like so:

```
:- op(950, fy, *).
*_0.

solve(A) :-
  * A = [[day1, fruit1, nut1], [day2, fruit2, nut2], [day3, fruit3, nut3],
         [day4, fruit4, nut4], [day5, fruit5, nut5]],

  Days = [monday|_/*[tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday]*/],
  Days = [day1|_/*[day2, day3, day4, day5]*/],

  * Fruits = [apple,banana,pear,mango,apricot],
  * permutation(Fruits, [fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, fruit4, fruit5]),

  * Nuts = [almonds,pecans,cashews,peanuts,walnuts],
  * permutation(Nuts, [nut1, nut2, nut3, nut4, nut5]),

  % clue 1 - mango before apple
  * fruit5 \= mango,
  * member([C1,mango,_], A),
  * member([C2,apple,_], A), before_in_week(C1,C2,Days),
  % clue 2 - banana after almonds and peanuts, but before pear
  * fruit5 \= banana,
  * member([C1,banana,_], A),
  * member([C2,pear,_], A), before_in_week(C1,C2,Days),
  * member([C3,_,almonds], A), before_in_week(C3,C1,Days),
  * member([C4,_,peanuts], A), before_in_week(C4,C1,Days),
  % clue 3 - cashews before banana and apricot, but after peanuts
  * nut5 \= peanuts,
  * member([C1,_,cashews], A),
  * member([C2,_,peanuts], A), before_in_week(C1,C2,Days),
  * member([C3,banana,_], A), before_in_week(C3,C1,Days),
  * member([C4,apricot,_], A), before_in_week(C4,C1,Days),
  % clue 4 - pecans not night after almonds
  * nut5 \= almonds.
  % clue 5 - ate walnuts one night
```

In this program slice, which is a generalization of your original program, it boils down to the inability to succeed for

```
Days = [monday|_], Days = [day1|_]
```

You have to change there something. `day1` is a constant, it rather should be a variable.

Later, replace all `X \= const` by `dif(X, const)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest issue is that you are using atoms (`fruit4`) but you should use variables (`Fruit4`). Note the capitalization at the start.

Also, you're doing a permutation that you don't need. Prolog does all of the permutations you need via backtracking. That's what make Prolog such an interesting language.

Try this code:

```
?- solve(A),print_solve(A).

solve(A) :-
    A = [[monday,_,_],[tuesday,_,_],[wednesday,_,_],[thursday,_,_],[friday,_,_]],
%clue 1 - mango before apple
    before([_,mango,_],[_,apple,_],A),
% clue 2 - banana after almonds and peanuts, but before pear
    before([_,_,almonds],[_,banana,_],A),
    before([_,_,peanuts],[_,banana,_],A),
    before([_,banana,_],[_,pear,_],A),
% clue 3 - cashews before banana and apricot, but after peanuts
    before([_,_,cashews],[_,banana,_],A),
    before([_,_,cashews],[_,apricot,_],A),
    before([_,_,peanuts],[_,_,cashews],A),
% clue 4 - pecans not night after almonds
    append(H,[[_,_,almonds],[_,_,_]|T],A),
    (member([_,_,pecans],H);member([_,_,pecans],T)),
% clue 5 - ate walnuts one night
    member([_,_,walnuts],A),
    true.

print_solve([]).
print_solve([Head|Tail]) :-
    write(Head),
    nl,
    print_solve(Tail). 

before(X,Y,Days) :-
    append(A,B,Days),
    member(X,A),
    member(Y,B).
```

That gives me:

```
[monday, mango, peanuts]
[tuesday, apple, cashews]
[wednesday, apricot, almonds]
[thursday, banana, walnuts]
[friday, pear, pecans]
Yes.
```

Answer (score 1):

The puzzle can be easily solved by means of one of workhorses of Prolog: generate-and-test. The key is modelling expressions over domain variables (constraints) making easy to check if they are satisfied.

```erlang
snacks(Week) :-

    % model the problem with domain variables,
    % make the symbolic associations explicit

    % this is the 'generation phase'

    Nuts = [
        almonds:Almonds,
        cashews:Cashews,
        pecans:Pecans,
        peanuts:Peanuts,
        walnuts:_Walnuts
    ],
    Fruits = [
        apple:Apple,
        banana:Banana,
        pear:Pear,
        mango:Mango,
        apricot:Apricot
    ],

    % since we are going to use plain arithmetic, assign numbers before attempt to evaluate constraints
    assign_days(Nuts),
    assign_days(Fruits),

    % now the 'application symbols' are bound to integers, then we can
    % code actual constraint expressions in a simple way...

    % this is the 'test phase'

    % a) The apple was eaten later in the week than the mango.
    Apple>Mango,

    % b) The banana was eaten later in the week than both the almonds and peanuts,
    %    but earlier in the week than the pear.
    Banana>Almonds,Banana>Peanuts,Banana<Pear,

    % c) The cashews were eaten earlier in the week than both the banana and the apricot,
    %    but later in the week than the peanuts.
    Cashews<Banana,Cashews<Apricot,Cashews>Peanuts,

    % d) The pecans were not eaten the evening after the almonds.
    Pecans=\=Almonds+1,

    % e) Bill ate walnuts one night.
    % no constraints, just existance

    % when we get here, domain variables satisfy the constraints
    % just format the workspace in easy to read list
    findall((Day,Fruit,Nut),(
                nth1(NDay,['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday'],Day),
                memberchk(Fruit:NDay,Fruits),
                memberchk(Nut:NDay,Nuts)
            ),Week).

assign_days(Snacks) :-
    numlist(1,5,Nums),
    permutation(Nums,Perm),
    maplist([Day,_:Day]>>true,Perm,Snacks).
```